# Importing project to Android Studio changes permissions?

Tags: android

I 've imported an Eclipse project to Android Studio and now it has added 3 more permissions to the APK.

Coarse, Get Accounts, Use Credentials.

How do I remove these? It seems that they were added from the google play services lib somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by enforcing removal:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```